# Using WebClient to ping a web site

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, http-authentication

I have a tiny app that I wanting to run and ping an internal web site.  Here is the code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadString("http://MyServer/dev/MyApp");
}
```

However, it is throwing the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I have all the correct credentials to access the server.  I am thinking I don't know how to use WebClient very well and I just need to set properties on the client object.  Any ideas?

Comment: What authentication method does the website use?  Also, are you just wanting to ping that the server is up?  If so, you can just do a `HEAD` request and make sure it's not a 500 code or doesn't respond to the connection.

Comment: So do you want ping (ICMP) or "ping" (just verify that server and app are up)

Comment: You could argue that you already achieved your goal....

Comment: The web site is using Windows Authentication....and I am wanting to "ping" the server to keep it alive.  The performance on the initial page load is slow

Comment: If you enter that URL in Internet Explorer, does it come up? Or do you get the error? What about if you use Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Is the user account in which this app runs a domain / active directory user if you use windows authentication?

Comment: If I put the url into IE, the web site loads normally.  And the user account is mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.  I needed to use the NetworkCredentials() method of WebClient.  See below:

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("theUser", "thePassword", "theDomain"); 
        client.DownloadString("http://MyServer/dev/MyApp");
    }
```

[This is the URL that helped me](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/242194-getting-errors-when-i-tried-to-download-files-using-credentials/)