# Is it possible to trigger periodic events from a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, windows-services

I'm creating a WCF service (to be run in IIS) that a client can talk to. Periodically I want my server to send a heartbeat to a Master server.

At the moment the only way I see to do this is to create a second Windows Service that will send out the heartbeat.

Is there any way to get my original WCF service to run an event periodically so that I can get everything done with just one service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a good way in a WCF service

If the service is going to get some use you may be able to store the NextHeartBeat timestamp and every request check if it's time to send out a message to the master server.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do may be achieved with [server push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667014/push-data-to-client-without-using-callback-in-wcf) or [full-duplex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) approaches. But for heartbeat you might get around with a simple http ping using a *WebClient* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202933/using-webclient-to-ping-a-web-site). When self-hosting (non IIS) you can override *ServiceBase.OnStart/OnStop* and start/stop a timer to periodically trigger the ping.

However, hosting a WCF service in IIS usually means that your service is instantiated on a per-request basis so there is no service instance hanging around to send an enduring ping.

It depends on the purpose you need the heartbeat to the Master Server. Could you instead let the master server periodically do a request on the WCF service?

If you really are in the need for a long running service then hosting WCF in a Windows Service instead of IIS might be an option.